# Chrome extension: executing script before website's scripts

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using a content script that receives data from `chrome.storage.local.get` and then executes.

I want it to complete all execution before the website's scripts start executing.

The problem is: that getting data from `chrome.storage.local.get` takes time and is asynchronous, so it starts to execute before the website's scripts but finishes after.

Is there a way to fix it? Like, block the main thread before it finishes or something? Or pass information to it without using `chrome.storage.local.get`? Or should I delay all requests of the page with `chrome.webRequest`?

```js
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "match_about_blank" : true
    }
  ],
```

content.js:

```js
(async () => {
   // website's scripts are not yet executed
   let data = await chrome.storage.local.get("data");
   // website's scripts are already executed
})();
```

Comment: There's no way to delay it. The only flexible workaround is to use chrome.userScripts API to register the new code with new `data` literally inside (instead of `content_scripts` in manifest.json), but currently it requires the user to enable devmode in chrome://extensions. Depending on what's in `data` there may be other workarounds.

Comment: @wOxxOm I checked all methods, and I think the one you suggested is the best, another option is to update the normal content script file and reload the extension. You can copy it as an answer and I'll mark it solved. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a synchronous result out of an asynchronous operation in JavaScript. You just cannot do it.

Maybe you can do a MITM (Man In The Middle) with a proxy server, where you proxy that webpage to a server you control.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/proxy

Comment: How to do MITM if all websites are with SSL?